# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Async method on interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to `SaveChangesAsync()` from an interface that I implemented. Every other method on this interface seems to work fine. I debugged every task before the one that gives the error and everyone `IsCompleted`. I'm new to this so tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

`UserController` Just the constructor

```
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
private readonly IRoleRepository _roleRepository;

public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository,IRoleRepository roleRepository)
{
      _userRepository = userRepository;
      _roleRepository = roleRepository;
}
```

`UserController/Edit`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, EditViewModel model)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            List<IdentityRole> listaRoles = new List<IdentityRole>();
            IdentityRole Role = new IdentityRole();
            List<IdentityRole> listaSelectedRoles = new List<IdentityRole>();

            //Atribuir o nomeUtilizador ao modelo do Post
            var modelTemp = await base.CreateModel<EditViewModel>(_userRepository);
            Task taskModel = base.CreateModel<EditViewModel>(_userRepository);
            await Task.WhenAll(taskModel);
            bool test = taskModel.IsCompleted; //to debug: test = true;

            model.NomeUtilizador = modelTemp.NomeUtilizador;
            modelTemp = null;

            //buscar o utilizador com o id à base de dados
            user = await _userRepository.FindByIDAsync(id);
            var boo = _userRepository.FindByIDAsync(id).IsCompleted;    //to debug: boo = true;

            //Buscar roles da bd para uma lista
            var task = _roleRepository.ToListAsync();
            listaRoles = await task;
            var t = task.IsCompleted; //to debug: t = true;

            (...)

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    (...)
                    //Adicionar/remover roles a cada utilizador
                    foreach (var role in listaRoles)
                    {
                        await _userRepository.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name); //tested here: true aswell

                        foreach(var selectedRole in listaSelectedRoles)
                        {
                            if (role.Id == selectedRole.Id)
                            {
                               await _userRepository.AddToRoleAsync(user, selectedRole.Name);   //tested here: true aswell
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    user.Nome = model.Nome;
                    user.Email = model.Email;
                    user.UserName = model.Email;
                    user.PhoneNumber = model.Telemovel;

                    await _userRepository.UpdateAsync(user); //error
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!await ApplicationUserExists(user.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

`IUserRepository`

```
public interface IUserRepository : IDisposable
    {
        Task<List<ApplicationUser>> ToListAsync();
        Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIDAsync(string userId);
        Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName);
        Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user);
        Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName);
        Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName);
        Task<bool> AnyAsync(string userId);
        Task AddAsync(ApplicationUser user);
        Task DeleteAsync(string userId);
        void Update(ApplicationUser user);
        Task SaveChangesAsync();
        Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user);
    }
```

`UserRepository` Not every method for space saving

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIDAsync(string userId)
        {
            return _context.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(userId);
        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            return _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName == userName);
        }

        public Task<List<ApplicationUser>> ToListAsync()
        {
            return _context.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task AddAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            _context.ApplicationUser.AddAsync(user);
            return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }

        public Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
        {
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
            return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
        {
            _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
            return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }



        public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Like I said, I debugged every other method and their: `Status = RanToCompletion`.
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the exception trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several methods in your "repository" which start asynchornous operations but do not wait for them to complete. So you need to fix those methods:

```
public async Task AddAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    // need to await this one
    await _context.ApplicationUser.AddAsync(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
{
    // same story
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName)
{
    // same story
    await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes, when I was creating these methods i thought I needed a `return` of some sort. Why don't I need to return a `Task` ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques well you seem to understand how `async` works. For example `Edit` method from your code returns ` Task<IActionResult>` , but you actually return `View` from it, which is just `IActionResult`. Same story here: because method is marked with `async` - it will already always return `Task`, so you don't need explicit return. If async method returns `Task<SomeType>`, like `Task<int>` - then you need to return value: `return 1;`, but not `Task`, because it's already always a `Task` (because you marked method as `async`).

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques note that your other methods are correct. If the only thing you do in method is calling another asynchronous method - you don't need to mark anything as `async` - just return result of that other method. For example: `Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIDAsync(string userId) { return _context.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(userId);}` - correct. `async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIDAsync(string userId) { return await _context.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(userId);}` - not correct (well, it will work, but there is no reason to do it).

Comment: I just need to mark a method as `async` when it has more than one asynchronous method in there so that they can `await`? @Evk

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques when there is more that one async method OR you have just one, but it's not last thing you do in that method. For example `async Task Method() {await DoSomething(); DoSomethingElse()}` < you have just one async call, but you need to do something else after it, so you can't just do `Task Method() {return DoSomething();}`

Answer (score 1):

try change this on **UserRepository**:

```
    public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

to this, for returning int value of **_context.SaveChangesAsync()**:

```
    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
            _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();               
    }
```

Comment: Oh, at the beginning I was trying to do that, but I didn't know what type to return. Why `<int>` tho?

Comment: because, if you see intellisense, the function _context.SaveChangesAsync() return the number of rows afecteds [EF saveChangesAsynk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx)